# Primeng confirmation dialog not getting invoked when called from inside the guard

Tags: angular, primeng

I have the following guard. This guard invokes the confirmation dialog if there is a any change in the component. The code reaches to the point

```
 this.confirmationService.confirm({
```

but after that it doesn't invoke the confirmation dialog.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UnsavedChangesWarningGuard implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate>{
  constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) {}

  canDeactivate(
    component: ComponentCanDeactivate,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {


    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
      if (component.unsavedChangesAvailable().hasChanges) {
          this.confirmationService.confirm({
            message: component.unsavedChangesAvailable().warningMessage,
            accept: () => {
              resolve(true);
            },
            reject: () => {
              resolve(false);
            },
            key: 'unsavedChanges'
          });
        }
        else {
          resolve(true);
        }
      });
  }
```

If I put the dialog code inside the component itself it works fine. It doesn't even give any error. Due to dialog not showing up it blocks all navigations outside the current route.